# Find and delete/change registry entry with powershell

Tags: powershell, search, registry, edit

I can get registry elements like this:

```
PS> $Registry_Key = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Lenovo\Access Connections\Locations\*\*\*"
PS> Get-ItemProperty -path $Registry_Key -name m_bSetBrowserPxySettings -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

PSPath                   : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Lenovo\Access Connections\Locations\BMZ-GmbH\AdptList\Adpt00
PSParentPath             : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Lenovo\Access Connections\Locations\BMZ-GmbH\AdptList
PSChildName              : Adpt00
PSDrive                  : HKLM
PSProvider               : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry
m_bSetBrowserPxySettings : 1

PSPath                   : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Lenovo\Access Connections\Locations\BMZ-GmbH\AdptList\Adpt01
PSParentPath             : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Lenovo\Access Connections\Locations\BMZ-GmbH\AdptList
PSChildName              : Adpt01
PSDrive                  : HKLM
PSProvider               : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry
m_bSetBrowserPxySettings : 1
```

But now I want to delete `m_bSetBrowserPxySettings` completely, or change the value to "0" for every match in this search. Change or delete doesn't matter. What do I have to add to my script to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

You can do it as follows:

```powershell
$Registry_Key = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Lenovo\Access Connections\Locations\*\*\*"
Get-ItemProperty -path $Registry_Key -name m_bSetBrowserPxySettings -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | % { Set-ItemProperty -path $_.PSPath -name m_bSetBrowserPxySettings "0" }
```

You need pipe the `Get-ItemProperty` command to:

```powershell
% { Set-ItemProperty -path $_.PSPath -name m_bSetBrowserPxySettings "0" }
```

`%` represents the `ForEach-Object` cmdlet. What it will do is iterate over each item in the collection you get out of the `Get-ItemProperty` command. `$_` represents the object in the pipeline, so this will change to the new item on each iteration.

`$_.PSPath` is the path to the registry key of the item. You can see this printed in the table in your question. You can use this value to pass to `Set-ItemProperty` along with your name and then set the value to whatever you want.

If you wanted to remove the item altogether, pipe to the following instead:

```powershell
% { Remove-ItemProperty -path $_.PSPath -name m_bSetBrowserPxySettings }
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than working with the path all the time you can just work on the item itself:

```
$Registry_Key = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Lenovo\Access Connections\Locations\*\*\*"
$item = Get-Item $Registry_Key
$item | Get-ItemProperty -name m_bSetBrowserPxySettings -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

Then to set it to 0:

```
$item | Set-ItemProperty -name m_bSetBrowserPxySettings "0"
```

Or to delete it:

```
$item | Remove-ItemProperty -name m_bSetBrowserPxySettings
```